# How to solve transactional logging in Java?

Tags: java, spring, logging, transactions

I want to achieve the following:

Inside of a transaction I want to generate multiple log messages. These log messages should be written only if the transaction gets committed successfully. If the transaction gets rolled back the log messages mustn't be logged.

I couldn't find anything to achieve this (using spring, hibernate, atomikos), so I wrote this little wrapper (I left out a couple of convenience-methods):

```
public class TransactionLogger {
    private Logger logger;
    private Map<Long, LinkedList<LogRecord>> threadBuffers =
        new HashMap<Long, LinkedList<LogRecord>>();

    public TransactionLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private void addRecord(LogRecord rec) {
        LinkedList<LogRecord> list =
            threadBuffers.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (list == null) {
            list = new LinkedList<LogRecord>();
            threadBuffers.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), list);
        }
        list.add(rec);
    }

    private LinkedList<LogRecord> getRecords() {
        if (threadBuffers.containsKey(Thread.currentThread().getId())) {
            return threadBuffers.remove(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        } else {
            return new LinkedList<LogRecord>();
        }
    }

    public void commit() {
        for (LogRecord rec : getRecords()) {
            rec.setLoggerName(logger.getName());
            logger.log(rec);
        }
    }

    public void rollback() {
        getRecords();
    }

    /**
     * If the resulting log entry should contain the sourceMethodName
     * you should use logM(Level,String,String) instead,
     * otherwise TransactionLogger.commit() will get
     * inferred as sourceMethodName.
     */
    public void log(Level l, String sourceClassName, String msg) {
        LogRecord rec = new LogRecord(l, msg);
        rec.setSourceClassName(sourceClassName);
        addRecord(rec);
    }

    /**
     * Same as log(Level,String,String), but the sourceMethodName gets set.
     */
    public void logM(Level l, String sourceClassName, String msg) {
        StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        LogRecord rec = new LogRecord(l, msg);
        rec.setSourceClassName(sourceClassName);
        if (trace != null && trace.length > 1) {
            rec.setSourceMethodName(trace[2].getMethodName());
        }
        addRecord(rec);
    }
}
```

What do you think of this approach? Are there any major or minor flaws or problems with it?
Or even better, are there any ready-to-use solutions for this?

**UPDATE:**

Since I am using JTA as well, I got a new idea. Would implementing the TransactionLogger as a receiver of a transaction-aware message queue solve the time issue or would it just make things more complex?

**UPDATE:**

I think logging to a database and then periodically writing log entries from that database into a file in a periodic task as suggested in the comments, is a very good solution to this problem:

PROs:

- Normal implementation afford
- integrates with TransactionManager
- Log entries in the log files may be ordered by timestamp

CONs:

- Log files are not up to date (depending of periodic-task-interval)
- database-structure dependent
- logging of simple non-transactional events becomes dbconnection-dependent
- probably bigger overall logging overhead

Here are the pros and cons I see with the wrapper I posted:

PROs:

- database and framework independent
- simple implementation
- log files are always up to date

CONs:

- Log entries in the log files are not ordered by event-timestamp but by "transaction-completition"-timestamp (long transactions lead to very mixedup log files.
- `rollback()` and `commit()` have to be invoked "manually", which can lead to programming errors (and possible OutOfMemoryError if invoking these methods is forgotten)

I think a combination of those two, like buffering log records in the "wrapper"-approach are worse than using one of the two mentioned approaches, because of the possible inconsistent log files (forgotten log entries due to an application crash).

My decision now is keeping my "wrapper". The following reasons are crucial for this decision (in order of importance):

1. I prefer log files that are always up to date over perfectly ordered log entries
2. Long transactions are very rare in my case
3. I am able to reduce the usage of `rollback()` and `commit()` to only a few methods.
4. This solution already exists by now.

*By the way: I'd like to improve my english. So if you notice any mistakes in my article, I will be glad if you point them out.*

**UPDATE:**

Simplyfied I'm using it like this:

```
/*
 * This objects contains one or more TransactionLogger(s) and exposes rollback()
 * and commit() through rollbackLogs() and commitLogs().
 */
@Autowired
private ITransactionalServer server;

public void someMethod(String someParam) {
    boolean rollback = false;
    try {
        /*
         * This method is for example annotated with @Transactional.
         */
        return server.someTransactionalMethod(someParam);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logError(ex);
        rollback = true;
    } finally {
        if (rollback) {
            server.rollbackLogs();
        } else {
            server.commitLogs();
        }
    }
}
```

Still this isn't perfect, but right now it seems a "good-enough-solution" to me. The next step will be using aspects to decorate my transactional methods.

**UPDATE:**

I'm adding this in my question, because I felt bad about accepting my own answer, although someone other got me on the way.

I am now using an AOP-approach basically with the following Logger. (In my real application I have more than one Logger like this and all those Loggers are managed by a custom singleton-manager.):

```
public class AopLogger extends Logger {

    public static AopLogger getLogger(String name) {
        LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
        Object l = manager.getLogger(name);
        if (l == null) {
            manager.addLogger(new AopLogger(name));
        }
        l = manager.getLogger(name);
        return (AopLogger)l;
    }

    private Map<Long, LinkedList<LogRecord>> threadBuffers = new HashMap<Long, LinkedList<LogRecord>>();

    public AopLogger(String name) {
        super(name, null);
    }

    public void beginTransaction() {
        LinkedList<LogRecord> list = threadBuffers.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (list == null) {
            list = new LinkedList<LogRecord>();
            threadBuffers.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), list);
        }
    }

    private void addRecord(LogRecord rec) {
        LinkedList<LogRecord> list = threadBuffers.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (list != null) {
            list.add(rec);
        } else {
            super.log(record);
        }
    }

    private LinkedList<LogRecord> getRecords() {
        if (threadBuffers.containsKey(Thread.currentThread().getId())) {
            return threadBuffers.remove(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        } else {
            return new LinkedList<LogRecord>();
        }
    }

    public void commit() {
        for (LogRecord rec : getRecords()) {
            rec.setMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            super.log(rec);
        }
    }

    public void rollback() {
        getRecords();
    }

    public void log(LogRecord record) {
        addRecord(record);
    }
}
```

and this Aspect:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Aspect
@Order(10)
public class AopLogManager implements Ordered {

    @Autowired
    private AopLogger logger;
    private Logger errorLogger = Logger.getLogger("ExceptionLogger");

    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public Object logTransaction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        logger.beginTransaction();
        Exception ex = null;
        try {
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ex = e;
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (ex != null) {
                logger.rollback();
                errorLogger.severe(ex.getMessage());
            } else {
                logger.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private int mOrder;

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return mOrder;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        mOrder = order;
    }
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I have the following lines:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="springTransactionManager" order="5"/>
```

This works fine until now.

PROs:

- database and framework independent
- simple implementation
- log files are always up to date
- `rollback()` and `commit()` are invoked automatically after each transaction

CONs:

- (Log entries in the log files are not ordered by event-timestamp but by "transaction-completition"-timestamp. I think this is not a big disadvantage, as the DB-actions realy take place the time the transaction is commited and the LogRecords of one transaction are still ordered correctly.)

Comment: Would you lose the exact ordering of events in the log file if running multi-threaded?

Comment: Probably yes! That's a good point and I will test it later on. To avoid further problems with it, I will set the millies in commit() until I know more about it. Thanks!

Comment: The most obvious solution seems to be to log to a database table...

Comment: Yes I thought of this as well and I would prefer this solution, but unfortunately I have to log to files...

Comment: @cherouvim: Because I have to be able to view the logs even if the database is down, corrupted or anything... it's a requirement, my software has to meet.

Comment: @AlexS, take look at log4j NDC http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html .

Comment: @StasKurilin: Can you be a bit more precise? How is NDC supposed to help me "dropping/forgetting" logentries on transaction rollback? That's my main intention.

Comment: @AlexS: Could you be using the database as a transactional storage medium and then have another scheduled job which would be copying db logs to file logs with, let's say, half an hour of delay? Or do the file logs need to be "very live"?

Comment: @cherouvim: That's a good suggestion. I will consider using this appoach as it is very clear and simple. But it will not solve the timing issue, because every time the scheduled job runs there may be "earlier" logentries that are not commited, yet.

Comment: @AlexS: The entries in the database should be in order, right? The job should decide on which entries to write down to the logfiles. Probably you'd need a pointer to the last db log entry written.

Comment: Since you have a multithreaded logger, I suppose you are synchronizing the class or using a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: No. Since I'm using the thread-id as key in the map, I don't think threads will corrrupt each others data.

Comment: Without knowing your full app, this is potentially disastrous. You could **lose** transactions due to code defects; aka your code has a bug, transaction comes in, bug occurs, exception raised, transaction rolled back - no log of the event exists.

My suggestion would be to log events as they occur and then log a "transaction rolled back" message. Operator would be able to see that the transaction was rolled back.

This vastly simplifies the solution - just log as you go, and when the transaction is complete, write a "transaction complete" or "transaction rolled back".

Comment: I am using the above approach, which is not integrated in any transactionmanager. Thus I have to do commit and rollback manually for this Logger. In practice this means I try-catch my transactional methods: On exception I rollback the log and log the exception. Otherwise I commit the exception. This means I have the informations about errors and only those logmessages of commited transactions. My next step is to do this using aspects... but I don't have the time right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don´t you create an aspect and implement an advice, especially, an After returning advice, check the documentation of spring this is available since 2.0:

```
Types of advice:

Before advice: Advice that executes before a join point, but which does not have the ability to prevent execution flow proceeding to the join point (unless it throws an exception).

After returning advice: Advice to be executed after a join point completes normally: for example, if a method returns without throwing an exception.

After throwing advice: Advice to be executed if a method exits by throwing an exception.

After (finally) advice: Advice to be executed regardless of the means by which a join point exits (normal or exceptional return).

Around advice: Advice that surrounds a join point such as a method invocation. This is the most powerful kind of advice. Around advice can perform custom behavior before and after the method invocation. It is also responsible for choosing whether to proceed to the join point or to shortcut the advised method execution by returning its own return value or throwing an exception.
```

if you only need to log if every thing its OK, then create the advice and leave your code clean:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;

@Aspect
public class AfterReturningExample {

    @AfterReturning("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()")
    public void doAccessCheck() {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean using Aspects instead of the try-catch-finally-block? That's my next step. But isn't transaction-commit and rollback also done via aspects? Which aspect will be called first?

Comment: OK, I mean aspect. When you use an aspect you are using filters, if you debug your app using eclipse you can see the full chain of calls. transaction in fact is an aspect too, and it´s easy implemented with @Transaction annotation in your methods, interfaces and classes, see the Spring Documentation: [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

Comment: if you have any doubt about your dao layer make a full question about it XD. rollback it´s used in the tests for the persistence, dao and/or service layer, well i used in the annotations in me test classes, see the docs [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations).

Comment: i really don´t understand your last question!!, when you use aspect you intercept the call of a method and it´s executed before the method code it´s executed, i indicate above the meaning of advice which you can use to manage how you want to do in a method call.

Comment: see Spring Doc [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) Sorry, i fragment me answer because  the timer of this site. Hope it help you

Comment: To explain my last question: The problem is, that I would have the @Transactional-aspect and my logging aspect on the same method and I don't know which one will be executed first. It would be fatal if my 'logging'-aspect would be called prior to the 'transactional'-aspect, because I wouldn't know if the DB-commit was /will be successful. Anyway my plan was to implement this using aspects in a next step, but right now I just don't have the time and on top of that the the answer by rparree seems more promising and a lot more clean than using simple aspects...

Answer (score 5):

If you want a Logger only "commit" its log messages when the transaction is commited, then your best solution would be to have your Logger be a `XAResource` and use XA transactions. This means your XALogger receives a prepare/commit notification from the transaction manager. This way your XAResource becomes a "Resource Manager" participating in an XA transation. Your XALogger needs to be registered with the transaction manager just like JMS and JDBC resources are registered. 
You can either write a JCA implementation, or (easier) just register your XALogger with the current `java.transaction.Transaction`

`transaction.enlistResource(myXALogger)`

and have it implement `XAResource` [(JavaDoc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html)

Comment: Your answer seems very promising. Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to try things out. If I use @Transactional-annotation (or xml-based JTA configuration (atomikos) I would have to use a JCA-implementation, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying it achieve with the `rec.setMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());`
The logged event occurred at the record creation time, not at the commit time. It's merely buffered in RAM until the commit time. By overriding it in this way you log the commit time rather than the event occurrence time. In reading the log you'll have to have some indication of actual ordering, or you won't be able to interpret causal relationships.

Your solution also suffers from problems in crash recovery situations. The transaction manager will process the commit for transactional resources, but the volatile log messages will be lost. That may or may not be tolerable, depending on your requirements.

Comment: The solution is not yet designed to be integrated into a transactionmanager. I'll post more infos on WE.

Answer (score 0):

So, I want to pick up where the comments left you :)
@MichaelBorgwardt suggests to log to a database and @cherouvim added that you should write the log entries from the database to the file periodically.

Its also possible to start the transformation of the log entries to the file directly after the transaction has been committed by a distinct Thread (that way avoiding the gap between committing and having it in the file).

Another possibility would be to write a log file for every transaction. On 'rollback' you delete it. On 'commit' you append it to your already existing logfile (or you decide to not have a single logfile anyway but a logdir and on 'commit' you move the single logfile).

Answer (score -4):

There's [a section about Logging](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e743) in the Spring Reference.

It shows how to configure different logging frameworks, among them [log4j](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e826)

In your case the last line of the config would be:

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.transactions=DEBUG
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question/ topic. It is not about how to get log-output, but how to not log messages that were created during a transaction (for excample in user code saying "did this and that"), that was rolled back... If you know any logging-framework that's capable of this...